# Change bitbucket repository in pycharm

Tags: pycharm, bitbucket

I have a Bitbucket repository setup in PyCharm. This works fine but I now want to change the name of the repository it saves to. Unfortunately I can't find where to change the name (having forgotten where I originally did this!).

Can anyone tell me where the appropriate setting is in PyCharm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on whether you are using git or mercurial.

If you use mercurial, you can just change the repository in your `hgrc` file in the `.hg` folder in your repository folder.

For git it should be in `.git/config` in your repository folder. PyCharm should then take the settings from this file.

Comment: Excellent! Thanks for that.

Comment: If this has solved your problem, you can mark the question as solved.

Comment: But next time if you have a repository problem you should write whether you are using git or mercurial.

Comment: Well if I had known that made a difference I would :)